Sinónimo para "chapuza" en Latam
Hablando con un compañero argentino sobre malas prácticas en la codificación de software, me sorprendí al descubrir que el término "chapuza", ampliamente usado tanto en nuestro sector como en cualquier ámbito aquí en España, era totalmente desconocido para él.
De acuerdo con el DRAE, chapuza significa


f. Trabajo hecho mal y sin esmero.


Por poneros un ejemplo de uso general, imaginaros que tenéis una cañería con fugas de agua, y en lugar de cambiar la cañería o soldarla, el fontanero usa chicle (goma de mascar) para taponar las filtraciones. A priori, el arreglo no ofrece muchas garantías.
En España eso es una chapuza. También llamada ñapa, aquí en el Sur de España, aunque no lo recoge el DRAE.
Mi pregunta es: ¿existe un sustantivo que sea sinónimo de chapuza en Argentina? Cualquier otra variante latina de otros paises es igualmente bienvenida.

En Guatemala se dice chapuz y no chapuza, y el que lo hace es un "chapucero".

@jachguate Aquí en Andalucía se emplea "chapu" también, quizás sea la misma palabra, pero pronunciar la z y la d al final no es lo nuestro ;-P

Nunca  he escuchado "chapuza" en Colombia

Trabajé en equipos de software. La manera en la que oí el equivalente de chapuza a alguna solucion, técnicamente deficitiaria, o insegura, era nombrarla como una chanchada (chancho=cerdo, puerco, por lo tanto equivalente a "porquería", algo sin valor, como la suciedad de un puerco)
Una manera común de nombrar un trabajo flojo e insolvente, en Argentina, sería desacreditarlo como una chantada
Esta palabra es una típica derivada del lunfardo Rio-Platense y la caracterización histórica de chantapufi, (de la que derivó "chanta", como su apócope),  para referir a alguien poco serio, que dice ser o hacer lo que no puede. Como un estafador de poco monta, y en definitiva alguien un poco patético.
El termino del argot tanguero (lunfardo) chantapufi   proviene del genovés "ciantapuffi", lo cual significa "que no paga sus deudas". Hoy, alquien así es nombrado simplemente como un chanta (de ahí la mención de chantada, por estar producida por alguien sin los calificativos necesarios)
De igual manera, mis compañeros en Argentina probablemente entenderían aún el calificativo (más gracioso) de una chantapufiada aplicable para un código sub-óptimo y chapucero, por estar escrito sin fundamento ni cuidado

Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Cuál de las tres crees que es más común? Lo del sw era para ofrecer algo de contexto, pero buscaba un equivalente de chapuza para cualquier ámbito. ¿Eso se cumple?

Por otro lado, supongo que chanchada viene de chancho, que si no me equivoco es sinónimo de cerdo o marrano. Marranada quizás es algo más peyorativo que chapuza. ¿Se cumpliría lo mismo entre chanchada y chantada?

Si, perdón por la aclaración tardía: chancho = marrano, cerdo, puerco. De ahí que chanchada sea el equivalente de porqueria (sucio, de poco valor, por   derivar de puerco; el producido de un puerco)

Definitivamente el uso más comun, y extrapolable a cualquier ámbito sería el de  "chantada" (el producido de un chanta, es decir a manos de alguien sin conocimientos ni seriedad)

No acaba de convencerles "chantada" a dos de mis compañeros argentinos. Según ellos, se acerca más a mentira, timo o engaño que a chapuza :-( Desconocían totalmente que procedía del lunfardo chantapufi, lo de chantapufiada les convence aún menos.

Aunque las explicaciones que aparecen aquí sí parecen corresponderse a chapuza

Los chilenos no usamos ninguna de las palabras indicadas por Danielillo, pero sí "chanta" mencionada aquí. Pienso que la importamos de Argentina, como muchas otras cosas de la cultura popular. También usamos "charcha" y "rasca" con el mismo significado, pero solo los adjetivos.

@Rodrigo Interesante. Puedes añadirlo como una nueva respuesta.

@Rodrigo Aunque lo indicaba en el texto, he modificado el título para acomodar cualquier país.

En Colombia usamos la siguiente la palabra para referir a ese concepto del trabajo o actividad que se realiza sin esmero:

chambonada

Y esta para referirse a la persona

chambona


champonada (como chapucería) son dos calificativos que se usarían también

Hay muchas palabras en España que no tienen una correspondencia en Argentina y supongo que tampoco en otros países de Latinoamérica. Personalmente tuve un gran problema intentando definir la palabra "cutre" a unas amigas argentinas.
En Argentina se utiliza changa para un trabajo rápido y barato hecho por un no profesional. Esto no implica que esté mal hecho pero sí falta de profesionalidad. El que realiza este tipo de trabajos, el "manitas" como dicen en España, es un changarín.
Pero la palabra changa se aplica a trabajos de arreglos varios, no aplicable al ejemplo de la pregunta respecto a codificación.
Yo escogería:

Un mamarracho


Un arreglo trucho

Trucho se usa más para describir algo falso, pero también puede usarse para describir un trabajo de baja calidad.
Berreta


adj. coloq. Arg. De mala calidad. Es una confección muy berreta.


Por extensión, berreteada. Aunque creo que es un poco antigua, si es común escuchar – ¡No seas berreta! – dirigido a alguien que hace o intenta hacer una chapuza.

Sí, "changa" ya la había descartado mi compañero. Se corresponde con la primera acepción de "chapuza" pero no con la segunda.

Tengo otra, la añado a la respuesta
